# Unicode in comment URLs

Tags: support

How do I handle unicode in the URL put into a comment?

For [example](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5812/how-do-you-say-asian-fast-food-restaurant-using-chinese-frying-pan-in-english#comment8682_5812), adding a link to `http://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/Chińczyk` without it breaking on the `ń`.

Comment: Try: http://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/Chi%C5%84czyk